# How to use jsdoc with .tsx file

Tags: reactjs, jsdoc

I want to use jsdoc, a very good tool to generate doc by comments. However, I have just .tsx file, and when I try to use jsdoc with .tsx file, it doesn't work ..

Are there configurations, or parameters to do this ?

This is the error of jsdoc :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The same question is answered here: [Is there any way to use `jsdoc` with `.ts` files? Maybe transpile with babel then use jsdoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56357904/17691588).

You can either compile ts to js and then generate doc or add compiler configuration to jsdoc.config or use specific documentation generator for TypeScript ([TypeDoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedoc)).