# Is there any way to use `jsdoc` with `.ts` files? Maybe transpile with babel then use jsdoc?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

Is there anyway to use jsdoc with typescript file?
I tried using `jsdoc-babel` with this config

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "node_modules/jsdoc-babel"
  ],
  "babel": {
    "extensions": [
      "js",
      "es6",
      "jsx",
      "ts",
      "tsx"
    ]
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work, maybe we can transpile ts files manually and then generate jsdocs?
I know of alternatives like typedoc but it lacks many important features.

So do you guys use jsdoc with typescript anyhow?

Answer (score 14):

Although as stated by @Remi `TypeDoc` is a better fit for TypeScript, I use JSDoc for better jsdoc to markdown conversion (as of this writing).

## Method 1:

Compile TypeScript and use JSDoc with compiled code

`> tsc && nodemon node_modules/.bin/jsdoc -c jsdoc.json dist/**/*`

## Method 2:

I'm using below method with jsdoc2markdown (which uses jsdoc). Using `jsdoc-babel`, `@babel/cli`, `@babel/core`, `@babel/preset-env`, `@babel/preset-typescript` with below jsdoc configuration:

```
{
  "source": {
    "includePattern": ".+\\.ts(doc|x)?$",
    "excludePattern": ".+\\.(test|spec).ts"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "plugins/markdown",
    "node_modules/jsdoc-babel"
  ],
  "babel": {
    "extensions": ["ts", "tsx"],
    "ignore": ["**/*.(test|spec).ts"],
    "babelrc": false,
    "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": true } }], "@babel/preset-typescript"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/proposal-class-properties", "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread"]
  }
}
```

This configuration:

- Excludes your-file.test.ts, your-file.spec.ts and your-file.js files from compilation and documentation.
- Includes your-file.ts, your-file.tsdoc and your-file.tsx
- Using `@babel/preset-env`, targets current node version for conversion. (You can change and test it according to your needs) => See the preset-env documentation
- Using `@babel/preset-typescript` gives babel the capability to parse TypeScript

### Tips & Tricks

#### JSDoc Comments Disappear

[Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) removes some JSDoc comments during transpilation:

- babel/babel#6898: [transform-flow-strip-types removes all jsdoc comments](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6898)
- babel/babel#5512: [Babel very strange move comments](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5512)

There is a hacky fix for this by adding a STUB code as seen below:

```
let STUB = 1;

/**
 * Some description
 * @typedef {Object} Config
 * @property {string}  name  - Name of the config.
 * @property {string}  color - Color of choice.
 */
STUB = 1;

export type Config = {
  name: string;
  color: string;
};
```

<s>I wrote a wiki page for using TypeScript with jsdoc2md using jsdoc-babel long ago.</s>

It may help: https://github.com/jsdoc2md/jsdoc-to-markdown/wiki/How-to-document-TypeScript

## Method 3 (TypeDoc)

This is not directly what is asked, but strongly related to it. Below workflow may be useful:

- Using TypeDoc to generate HTML pages.
- Using [typedoc-plugin-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedoc-plugin-markdown) to generate multiple MarkDown pages.
- Using [concat-md](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-md) to generate single MarkDown page from multiple MarkDown pages. (This is an npm package developed by me lately to solve my JSDoc/TypeScript single page MarkDown requirement.)

**Example**

```
$ typedoc --plugin typedoc-plugin-markdown --mode file --out docs
$ npx concat-md --decrease-title-levels --dir-name-as-title docs > README.md
```

Answer (score 2):

Although using JSDoc in combination with Typescript has certain benefits, such as:

- the structure is gleaned directly from the source
- annotations for TypeScript are much more compact

The downside is that adopting TypeScript requires a large amount of work required to fit the build tools into your current processes (as you currently are experiencing)

Instead, you can use something like http://typedoc.org/

It will continuously keep your documentation changes on watch and will re-build on codebase changes.

Source: https://blog.cloudflare.com/generating-documentation-for-typescript-projects/#whynotjsdoc

Answer (score 2):

Try out the JSDoc plugin for typescript, which is a part of better-docs toolset: https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/better-docs.