# jsdoc fails with *.js generated from *.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I'm trying to generate documentation for a simple typescript class:

```
export class Address
{
    /**
     * @param street { string } - omit building number
     * @param city { string } - short names like "NYC" are fine 
     */
    constructor(
        private readonly street: string,
        private readonly city: string){}
}

export class Person
{
    /**
     * @param name { string } - private name only
     * @param address { Address } - home address
     */
    constructor(
        private readonly name: string,
        private readonly address: Address){}
}
```

I compile it to `*.js` and generate a `*.d.ts` file as well:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --declaration main.ts
```

When I generate documentation, I just get the word **Home** and **nothing else**:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/jsdoc --verbose ./main.js
```

Comment: Is it relative to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720894/is-there-any-way-to-use-jsdoc-with-ts-files-maybe-transpile-with-babel-the?

Comment: @AndreyBessonov, yes, it is related to typedoc, though like it says in that answer, I was hoping to use jsdoc for better markdown support

Comment: Not sure if it really matters, but from a glance order of your JSDoc token does not match that what JSDoc specs shows. `@param name { type } - comment` should rather be `@param {type} name - comment` (At least it is that way on https://jsdoc.app/howto-es2015-classes.html )

Answer (score 0):

I had put my ".js" and ".d.ts" files in "dist" folder.

You can see my jsdoc config file, may it helps you,
And here I had use "clean-jsdoc-theme", but it doesn't matter, it will also work for default theme.

jsdoc.json :-

```
{
  "source": {
    "include": [
      "dist/User/index.js",
      "dist/Organization/index.js",
      "dist/Application/index.js",
      "dist/EndDevice/index.js",
      "dist/Gateway/index.js",
      "dist/Interfaces/Doc Common/docApp.interface.js",
      "dist/Interfaces/Doc Common/docEndDevice.interface.js"
    ]
  },
  "plugins": ["plugins/markdown"],
  "templates": {
    "cleverLinks": true,
    "monospaceLinks": true
  },
  "opts": {
    "template": "node_modules/clean-jsdoc-theme",
    "readme": "./readme/readme.md",
    "recurse": true,
    "destination": "./docs/",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "verbose": true,
    "theme_opts": {
      "default_theme": "dark",
      "search": true,
      "title": "Test",
      "homepageTitle": "Docs"
    }
  },
  "markdown": {
    "hardwrap": false,
    "idInHeadings": true
  }
}
```

And my package.json file:-

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "jsdoc -c jsdoc.json",
  },
```